# Shamir's Secret Sharing Computation time

Tags: secret-sharing

Hello for my thesis I am making research  about SSS computational time.

Based on **(K,N)**  threshold scheme
Where **K**  is the  minimum number of shares to rebuild the secret and 
**N** is the number of shares in which the secret will be divided

Which value affects more the computational time? K or N

I think K is it right?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: If this is a *thesis* (that is, you're turning it in as a part of an academic degree), you might want to try doing a bit of research, say, by reading the wikipedia article on SSS, and looking through the equations...

Comment: You think it is K. Why do you think that? Can  you clearly describe to us why you think that is the answer?

Comment: You might also want to consider "the computational time of what?".   SSS consists of two parts (generating the $N$ shares, and then recombining $K$ of them); which of the two operations are you considering (or is it both)?

Comment: Sorry I Didn't explain very well my problem.
Let me restart from the beginning..
I am implementing the sss for generate a random number into a p2p network.
for computational time I mean the time that each node of the network will spend for generate the secret and for rebuild it.

After looking the equation I realize that K is value the most effect the rebuild because with high k I will have a longer polynomial

I think now I undestand the situation...

Answer (score 1):

To find out how the computational time differs between the variables *K* and *N*, I suggest you analyze your implementation of the algorithm. Different algorithms can have different computational times for variables.

An easy example is by looking at the computational time for the variable *n* in sorting algorithms, in which *n* is the size of the list of numbers you wish to sort (in either ascending or descending order). A multitude of algorithms have been developed to sort a list of *n* random numbers and the computational time depends on the implementation of the algorithm. Using the BubbleSort algorithm gives a computational time of $O(n^2)$, while the HeapSort algorithm has a computational time of $O(n \times log(n))$.

After implementing the secret sharing scheme, you can analyze how the computational load changes by increasing either *K* or *N* and figure out the computational time.